# A global implicit function theorem

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

The following result can be found in the paper "Natural operations on
differential forms" by Richard S. Palais:

Corollary 4.3: "Let $f_{1}, \ldots , f_{n}$ be $n$ real valued functions of $n$
real variables. Necessary and sufficient conditions that 
the mapping $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ 
defined by $f(x) = (f_{1}(x), \ldots , f_{n}(x))$ 
be a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ onto itself are: 
(1) $\det (df_{i}/dx_{j})$ never vanishes. 
(2) $\lim_{||x||\rightarrow \infty} ||f(x)|| = \infty$."

If we assume that each of the $f_{i}$:s are smooth functions
also of some other variables in $y \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, is 
satisfaction of the above conditions for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$
necessary and sufficient for the $x_{i}$:s to be functions of 
$y$ in the entire $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (intuitively the answer is yes I suppose)?

Also, if $f$ is smooth in $x$ and $y$, will $x$ be smooth as a function of $y$?

(I just realized my question is related to a previous one: [How to "globalize" the inverse function theorem?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47612/how-to-globalize-the-inverse-function-theorem))

Best regards
 
Olav

Comment: Your questions are purely local in nature and therefore follow by the standard inverse function theorem. Voting to close.

Comment: Why do you think they are purely local? The second condition, that the norm of f tends to infinity, does not appear in the usual inverse function theorem

Comment: In case someone else comes across this. A motivation for why the second condition above is needed is of course given by considering the map $x \rightarrow e^{x}$. Obviously the derivative never vanishes, but $e^{x} = a$ has no solution for $a \leq 0$.